# Does SQL Table Column is assigned with column number

Tags: sql-server, database-design, table

In Table, we can see there is number assigned automatically (line number) is the same thing is available for the columns (column number) and how can we get that number?
I need a SQL query to find the column number not the number of columns.

Comment: Is the "line number" value in your question from the SSMS grid results? That is generated by the SSMS client application tool. Perhaps the column number you want is the `ORDINAL_POSITION` column of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` meta-data view.

Answer (score 1):

The row number you get in SSMS (I'm presuming you were refering to this number) is not generated by SQL but by SSMS (so it doesn't really exist in your database).

SQL does have a "number" associated with each columns (their IDs) and you could get those with a query like this one:

```
  select c.column_id from sys.columns c 
  join sys.objects o on o.object_id =c.object_id
  where o.name = 'YourTableName'
```

I'm not sure it will do exactly what you expect it to do, so if you could specify why you want those columns number, we will be in a better position to give you a clearer answer.

Comment: I need to create a dynamic update query which will work for more then 50 tables and all  the table will have different column count. That's why I need way to find the column number

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to do your own data management, independently of the data management facilities offered by SQL Server.  It's usually better to understand what SQL Server can do for you, and make use of those features.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have database of 100's table and lots of transaction are going. I make a Dynamic CT Query to track those changes which are working but i need dynamic query to reflect those changes Update Insert and Delete on the destination. We are facing difficulties in Update Query

Answer (score 1):

You cannot refer to a column by its number. (Nor can you refer to a row by some number, as already said, the row numbers you see in an SSMS grid are generated by SSMS.)

So, when you write DML, columns do *not* have numbers. You can't, in an UPDATE say, refer to "the second column" as `2`. That concept just doesn't exist.

SQL Server does, however, *internally* have IDs for tables and columns, and they happen to be integer class numbers. But that doesn't mean that these are available at the DML level.

So if you add more details on what you need to achieve, at a much higher level, you might get ideas and design suggestions. By this I mean more details than you have in the comment to Dominique's answer. This should be done in a new post, considering it will be a new type of question.